# How to deploy C++ app on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

My c++ app depends on GCC, MongoDB C++ driver and Boost. My current way is to keep the OS consistent. I develop C++ on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit Desktop, and deploy it on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit server. Also I should install the same version of dependencies on target server.
But If I want to develop my C++ app on Ubuntu 13.04 and use newest Boost, MongoDB driver and GCC 4.8.1, which way is easy to deploy C++ app on Ubuntu 12.04 server.

1. static linking
2. Dynamic linking, also deploy all dependencies to target server?

Which way is simple? Sometimes, I cannot compile libraries on target server.

Comment: Have you looked into "cmake" for managing dependencies and easy rpm building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dependencies are small easiest way is to compile everything statically. It is fairly easy during the build step, and nothing fancy is needed. However, with bigger libraries, and a bigger project this might get inconvenient.

I think that best practice would be to compile dependencies into shared objects ship them along the binaries and execute stuff in a way that `ld` will look for your stuff 1st. I think it's possible by for example using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/where/did/i/ship/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH my_binary`.

It can be somewhat cumbersome as you need to set up your build system to compile stuff as shared objects and properly pack everything.

I'm pretty sure some of the pre-compiled programs that are shipped for linux work this way. Strangely, I can't find any custom pre-compiled app under my hand at the moment.

Comment: I should start from static linking now. It's easy and my app is not very big.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application. If your application consists of only one specific binary, then static linking of all C++ libraries is in order. You can safely link dynamically all C libraries, as the C ABI is unchanging; this just leaves you with version dependencies. However in most cases the major SO-Name verions are mostly compatible and libraries of differing major SO-Name can be installed in parallel. So I'd rely on the package manager to install those. C++ libraries are tricky due to lack of a common ABI. Even a mere compiler version bump can make them incompatible *sigh*.

Comment: Though the right way would be to actually make a package for that Linux distribution.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Well, in the Blender project it was decided that making a universally working tarball distributable would be better than packages. And I have to agree, because distributions can easily make a package from that, while people who use niche distributions can also use it.

Comment: That's right. But imagine a world where all packages come with all its dependencies link statically. That'd be a big mess. There are pros and cons of both approaches, as always :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Actually that would largely reduce the mess. There's not a small number of computer scientists and programmers (John Carmack to name a well known one) that conclude, that introducing dynamic linkage was mistake. A nice overview on the issue can be found at http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/dynamic-linking/