# deploy C++ wxWidgets on linux mint

Tags: c++, linux, deployment, wxwidgets

I've written an app with CodeBlocks using wxWidgets and I am unable to run it on Linux Mint. My development computer is a virtual machine running Linux Mint (i686) and my deployment computer is Linux Mint on bare metal (x86_64).
LDD shows:

```
NEEDED               libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0
NEEDED               libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

Each of these libraries is included on both computers.  I've followed the thread [How to deploy C++ app on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870992/how-to-deploy-c-app-on-linux) but it was not helpful.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Make sure you cross-compiled your app with `x86_64` library.

Comment: @JosephRand, you probably need to create 2 distribution packages: one for x86 (aka 32-bit) and one for x86_64 (aka 64-bit) distributions.

Comment: My 64-bit install has the 32 bit libraries and they work because I run Virtualbox on that machine and libc6 has Multi-Arch: same. Do I need to test for any additional libraries to verify that the 32-bit libraries are on the deployment machine?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. It turns out that I required the 32-bit GTK+ libraries onto my 64-bit system. In doing that I got the app to work. I don't know yet if this messed up the rest of my system. Can 32-bit and 64-bit GTK+ libraries coexist on one system?

Comment: In other words - I had already installed ia32-libs but needed to add libwxgtk3.0-0:i386 and then re-install ia32-lib.